How to add content before cart item's short content (wocommerce - 9.0.2)
I have woocommerce site and i am using blocks for checkout and cart pages...
i want to add simple text that comes from single product acf field before cart item description,
something like this,

in the red part i want that content.
i already tried some hooks like,
woocommerce_get_price_html, woocommerce_cart_item_price..
but i think it's not working with woocommerce blocks.
please let me know what should i try to get my desired result...

You should to use hook woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'cd_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_action' );

/**
 * Function for `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` action-hook.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function cd_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_action(){

    // action...
}


It's not working.

Yes, you are correct in case of block checkout page we need different approach because previous hooks not working in this case, please check the given link. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/43010#issuecomment-1892389514
Also I suggest you to go through the https://developer.woocommerce.com/2023/08/07/extending-the-woocommerce-checkout-block-to-add-custom-shipping-options/ which points you in right direction.
